# Understanding CGRect coordinate system and ios drawing

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I am really confused about how a CGRect is interpreted and drawn. I have the following routine to draw a rectangle:

```
let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
ctx.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
ctx.cgContext.setStrokeColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
ctx.cgContext.setLineWidth(1)
ctx.cgContext.addRect(rectangle)
ctx.cgContext.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
```

Now I was expecting this to draw a rectangle at the origin of the screen with the width and height of 100 (pixels/points, not sure about this).

However, I can barely see the drawn rectangle. Most of it seem to lie outside the screen (on the left hand side).

Changing this to:

```
let rectangle = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
```

Still around half the rectangle is outside the screen.

Is the origin of this CGRect at the bottom right? I am not sure how this is all getting interpreted.
I thought if the origin is at the center of the rectangle, then surely the second call should show the whole rectangle?

[EDIT]

I am running this on iphone X running ios 14.4.

[EDIT]
So, the full drawing code is as follows. This is part of a View. So, in the end the view image is assigned to the image we draw on

```
func show(on frame: CGImage) {
        // This is of dimension 480 x 640
        let dstImageSize = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        let dstImageFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()

        dstImageFormat.scale = 1
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: dstImageSize,
                                               format: dstImageFormat)

        let dstImage = renderer.image { rendererContext in
            // Draw the current frame as the background for the new image.
            draw(image: frame, in: rendererContext.cgContext)
            
            // This is where I draw my rectangle
            let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
            rendererContext.cgContext.setAlpha(0.3)
            rendererContext.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
            rendererContext.cgContext.setStrokeColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
            //rendererContext.cgContext.setLineWidth(1)
            rendererContext.cgContext.addRect(rectangle)
            rendererContext.cgContext.drawPath(using: .fill)
        }
        
        image = dstImage
    }
```

So, from what I can tell, it should draw it on the context of the image and should not go out of bounds with the parameters I gave.

I mean, the context is that of the bitmap that has been initialized to 480 x 640. I am nt sure why this is shown out of bounds when I view it on the device. Should this bitmap/image not be shown correctly?

Comment: CGRect's origin is at the top-left

Comment: You should include more context about where/how this `CGRect` is getting drawn on the screen. For example, macOS and iOS have flipped coordinate systems. And, of course, you'd want to be sure that you're correctly interpreting where the parent of this CGRect really is on the screen. Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: @aheze Thanks for that. I am really at a loss as to why the full rectangle does not get rendered.

Comment: @jnpdx I will work on that now. I am running this on ios 14.4

Comment: @aheze CGRect's origin is wherever the drawing system puts it. The struct itself imposes no orientation. From the docs: "In the default Core Graphics coordinate space, the origin is located in the lower-left corner of the rectangle and the rectangle extends towards the upper-right corner. If the context has a flipped-coordinate space—often the case on iOS—the origin is in the upper-left corner and the rectangle extends towards the lower-right corner."

Comment: @RobNapier ah yeah. OP tagged iOS though so I assumed iOS

Comment: Even on iOS, this can go either way. In Core Text, the origin is in the lower-left. It's a common cause of people drawing upside-down text on iOS. The developer can also redefine the coordinate system in any affine-way they want.

Comment: To jnpdx's point, we need more than the iOS version. We need an example of how you're creating and positioning this context. It's very likely that the problem is your context is centered on the origin (very common when using layers, for example) and has nothing to do with how you're drawing *inside* the context.

Comment: @RobNapier Interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: @RobNapier How can I find the origin of my context?